# Magento show tax rate for each tax - magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, tax

System - configuration - Sales - Tax - Shop display Settings set to Yes the option "Display Full Tax Summary"
is showing tax like below

Grand Total Excl. Tax   Rs. 650.00 
SGST (9%) 
                                                              Rs. 117.00
CGST (9%) 
**Grand Total Incl. Tax Rs. 767.00**

***How to show each tax amount separately?***

Grand Total Excl. Tax   Rs. 650.00
SGST (9%)                                 Rs.  58.5
CGST (9%)                                 Rs.  58.5
**Grand Total Incl. Tax Rs. 767.00**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

go and copy `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\order\tax.phtml`

```
<?php if ($isFirst): ?>
                <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 <?php echo count($rates); ?>">
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($amount); ?>
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

and paste at `app\design\frontend\[theme_package]\template\tax\order - tax.phtml` And replace code as shown below:

```
<?php //if ($isFirst): ?>
                <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?> rowspan=" 1 <?php //echo count($rates); ?>">
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($amount / ($percent/(float)$rate['percent']) ); ?>
                </td>
            <?php //endif; ?>
```

check below link for full details :

https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/